# I want to disable all the checkboxes selection if "none" is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am creating a PHP form and can't figure out how to disable all the checkboxes if **NONE** option is selected.

```
<h5>HEALTH OF STUDENT</h5>
<p>Are there any physical, emotional, or other difficulties that we should be aware of?</p>
<table>
    <td>Hearing
        <input type="checkbox" name="Audition" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Vision
        <input type="checkbox" name="Vision" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Heart
        <input type="checkbox" name="Coeur" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Langage
        <input type="checkbox" name="Speech" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Asthme
        <input type="checkbox" name="Asthma" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Diabetes
        <input type="checkbox" name="Diabete" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Allergies
        <input type="checkbox" name="Allergies" value="Yes" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="Allergies" value="Yes" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="None" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>Other
        <input type="checkbox" name="Autre" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td>If other, Specify
        <input type="text" name="autre2" id="autre2" />
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no "None" option in your HTML. But you would need to use javascript. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see to do this is by adding a class to every of your checkbox that needs to be disabled by the NONE one and then deselect every one when you click on it with a [jQuery .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to grab them all :

```
<input class="isOneOfThem" type="checkbox" name="Audition" value="Yes" />
<input class="isOneOfThem" type="checkbox" name="Vision" value="Yes" />
<!-- etc.. -->
<input onchange="deselectAllOfThem(this)" type="checkbox" name="NONE" value="Yes" />
```

-

```
function deselectAllOfThem(noneOne) {
  if(noneOne.checked) { // if the NONE checkbox is checked
    // looking for every HTML elements with the isOneOfThem class
    // within the table element
    $('table').find('.isOneOfThem').each(function() {
      // just uncheck the element in the .each() loop
      $(this).prop('checked', false); 
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: If you're using JQuery you can simply do: `if (noneOne.checked) $('.isOneOfThem').prop('checked', false);`. There's no need for `find()` and `each()`.